# How do I set environment variables in pipenv?

Tags: python, pipenv

I need to set some access token environment variables for my python project that I am running in a pipenv. I will want to set these environment variables every time I start the pipenv.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

If you want to load automatically some environment variables each time you start the project, you can set a `.env` file at the root folder of the project, next to the `Pipfile`. See [Automatic Loading of .env](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/shell.html#automatic-loading-of-env).

You can run the following command from the right folder to create this .env file :

```
echo MY_TOKEN=SuperToKen >.env  # create the file and write into
echo MY_VAR=SuperVar >>.env     # append to the file
```

or just create it manually to obtain:

```
MY_TOKEN=SuperToKen
MY_VAR=SuperVar
```

This file will be loaded automatically with `pipenv shell` or `pipenv run your_command` and the environment variables will be available.

You can access/check them in your code with :

```
print(os.getenv('MY_TOKEN', 'Token Not found'))
```

Not sure about other IDE, but within Pycharm you need the plugin **Env File** to load it automatically (access Env File tab from the Run/Debug configurations).

---

You can add comments in this file with a leading `#`

```
# My test token
MY_TOKEN=SuperToKen
```

---

Note : Of course you must exclude this file from your version control (like git).

Comment: Just curious: is it possible to _unset_ environment variables when exiting a pipenv-managed environment? For the record, I'm using the postactivate/postdeactivate in virtualenvwrapper to do that.

Comment: @GeorgesMartin not sure to understand exactly what you need, when you quit a virtual env, the variables are not available anymore

Comment: indeed... I forgot that pipenv starts a new shell — virtualenv doesn’t

Comment: `pipenv run` throws an error, however `pipenv shell` works fine!

Comment: `Usage: pipenv run [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...Error: Missing argument "COMMAND".`

Comment: @bro-grammer, `pipenv run` expects a command  to launch in your environment like `pipenv run flask run`

Comment: @bro-grammer its a known issue: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2588

Comment: `pipenv install` doesn't seem to be loading this file though. Shouldn't it ?

Comment: @Bren i don't think so, `install` is a different part in the workflow logic. Could you specify an example of what you expect?

Comment: Remember to restart the shell when you change the environmental variable!!

Comment: Another way to make it work in PyCharm and command shell without any additional setup would be to use the python-dotenv package.

Comment: PRMoreau, for example, the user wants to install Pipenv dependencies (`pipenv install --dev`) with the option `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1`. Currently, user forced to use command `SETX PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT 1` or `export PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1`.

Comment: If user move `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1` to the file `.env`, [**the option has no effect**](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/Kristinita/sashaappveyordebugging/builds/49094233#L226). Thanks.